# Android Development - Missing USB driver LG

Tags: android, android-studio, driver, lg

I'm trying to use my phone (LG Access LTE - LG L31L on the TracFone/StraightTalk platform) for Android development and am trying to follow the instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html) to download the appropriate USB driver.  When I look in the provided list, there is nothing for my phone.  Does this mean I'm out of luck?  Is there a generic driver I can use?

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: I'm using Android Studio 1.1.0 on a Windows 8 machine.

UPDATE:

So I installed the Google driver as suggested but still no luck.

So far I've:

```
1) Installed the Google driver via the SDK manager in Android Studio as described [here][2] as my phone ((LG Access LTE - LG L31L on the TracFone/StraightTalk platform) does not have a driver on the company website linked [here][3] and [here][4].
2) Turned on developer options on my phone
3) Turned on USB debugging
4) When I connect the USB cable I select MTP
```

However when I open the Android Device Monitor in Android Studio my phone is still not there.  What else am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you need to install the Google USB Driver, instead. https://developer.android.com/sdk/win-usb.html

Comment: Please try my answer
[here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38780459/cannot-use-google-usb-driver/38783293#38783293) This may help you.

Answer (score 1):

When I have troubles installing my ADB driver, I simply use wifi-adb (requires a rooted phone):

> https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ttxapps.wifiadb

Some ROMs even provide this feature preinstalled.

This may not be the solution for your problem but it is a straight forward workaround that should require no driver installation.

**Edit:**

You are looking for the ADB driver for your phone, you will probably have more luck searching for ADB instead of USB driver ;)

The XDA-Developers community could have a solution for your question.

**A real solution to your problem could be this:**

You could try out the universal ADB driver:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/103583939320326217147/posts/BQ5iYJEaaEH

After installation you will have to go to your device-manager (windows), find the unknown device (your smartphone) -> "update driver software" -> "Search on your PC" -> "Select from a list of drivers..." -> "ADB device"

Comment: Good idea but the phone isn't rooted.

Answer (score 0):

In case of LG phones, you should install driver from here: http://www.lg.com/us/support

And if it still doesn't work, installing LG PC Suite may help.