# Cannot Use Google USB Driver

Tags: android, mobile, driver

I have an LG G4 and would like to use it for debugging apps during development. However, I cannot get the device to show up.

I have followed the steps to set the phone into debugging mode.

I have Android Studio and used SDK manager to download the latest SDKs and tools and also installed the Google USB driver.

I cannot see my phone in `chrome://inspect` nor does it list with "adb devices" nor does it show up in Android Studio.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that this answer isn't more clear for anyone who stumbles across it, but I wasn't able to pinpoint what fixed it.

1. I was never able to use the Google USB Driver (so technically, the question isn't really answered)
2. I was able to install the drivers from LG, but was not able to assign the driver to my device in Device Manager
3. However, my LG G4 is now working in both Android Studio and chrome://inspect.

The unclear part is that what I did was continuously update Android Studio and throw in a few system restarts. Some items had updates appear after installation which I processed. I also added a few more full SDKs (started with only the latest, 24* at the time of this writing and went back to 21*)  At some point during this process, my phone began to work.

I suspect there was a tool or SDK that did the trick and possibly didn't actually fix the issue until I restarted the computer.

Answer (score 0):

You need install LG Drivers for your G4. Go to http://www.lg.com/us/support and find yours.
EDIT:
Sometimes it doesn't work in Windows 8 and 10, so you need LG PC Suite.

Comment: Tried it on a Mac, just for giggles and it still doesn't work. But I'm about to try it on Windows machine.

Comment: Thanks! This forced me to go to the correct section of the lg site. If you search by product first, you don't get the option for drivers so you have to go to Software and drivers first, THEN choose your model. However, this still did not fix the issue.  :-(

Comment: Thanks again, but I'm running Windows 7 so the Windows 8 and 10 issues wouldn't affect me. I also have had the LG PC Suite the entire time....even months before I ever tried to use the phone for dev.

Comment: The last tricky way: when LG phone is connecting to PC, change MTP to PTP. I have faced many problem with LG devices in 3 PC. First PC I had to completely remove LG drivers by using this way (http://forum.xda-developers.com/lg-g3/help/answer-windows-8-8-1-detecting-lollipop-t2967574) and reinstall it. Second PC, I had to change MTP to PTP. And my current PC, it refused to work until I install LG PC Suite. What a tragedy!

Comment: sorry, I should have listed everything that I tried in my initial request, but I tried every single mode available and within each mode, tried to update the driver, but it didn't work.  Also, note that I ended up answering my own question here.

Answer (score 0):

If you already used any other android devices for debugging, then the ADB driver is ready to be used for your LG G4. Try following steps.

- **Connect phone using USB cable**
- **Open device manager >> right click on unidentified LG G4 >> Update Driver Software >> Browse my computer for driver software >> Let me pick from a list of device drivers on my computer >> Install an ADB driver from the list (install anyway)**

Comment: Now your device will list in Android Studio.

Comment: I tried that. When I browse to the Google USB folder, it says "no compatible drivers for your device found in this location."  I can see the *.inf file in the folder, so it's not missing.

Comment: Didn't help with Windows either.

Comment: It won't work because LG drivers is different to Google ADB driver